# Unable to process log with Python TimedRotationFileHandler Logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I'm Trying to log an application with below configs. Logging is working but the problem is i'm facing with TimedRotation of the file. Don't understand why but when the log rotation is happening it's removing all the current dated logs and just keeping latest 5-6 logs before the initial rotation of next day in that previous file.

#### How would I get my below config work like i want everyday logs just in datewise log file in respective folder without removing previous logs ?

> logging.ini

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,detailedConsoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=normalFormatter,detailedFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=normalFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_detailedConsoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=detailedFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_normalFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s loglevel=%(levelname)-6s logger=%(name)s %(message)s   call_trace=%(pathname)s L%(lineno)-4d

[formatter_detailedFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s loglevel=%(levelname)-6s logger=%(name)s %(funcName)s() L%(lineno)-4d %(message)s   call_trace=%(pathname)s L%(lineno)-4d
```

> logging.py

```py
import logging
import logging.config
from datetime import datetime
from logging import Logger
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from pathlib import Path
from epay.core.config import settings

# Project Directories
ROOT_LIB = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
APP_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


def get_logger(logger_name: str = "root") -> Logger:
    ## Setup loggers
    logging.config.fileConfig("epay/logging.ini", disable_existing_loggers=False)

    ## get root logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log_format = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-7s] [%(module)s:%(lineno)-4s] - [Func: %(funcName)-18s] - Exception: %(exc_info)s - %(message)s"
    )

    # Create year and month folders
    current_year = datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
    current_month = datetime.now().strftime("%B")
    log_folder = ROOT_LIB / "logs" / current_year / current_month
    log_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    fileHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
        str(log_folder / "epay.log"), when="midnight", interval=1
    )
    fileHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO if settings.DEBUG else logging.WARNING)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(log_format)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

    return logger
```